# users have access to ssas tabular instance without giving them a role

Tags: permissions, ssas

I have created a ssas tabular model. Testing the row level security base on a user I found out that it didn't work.

I tested it on an user which is not known in the SQL database and analysis services. When I ask the user connect to the Analysis Services in MS Excel, he was able to see all the data. All with the company network.

Do I need to change something in the configuration of the firewall/SQL Server/SSAS Tabular? I configure port 2382 for the SSAS Tabular instance.

I use SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition

I hope someone can help me with this. If more information is needed, please let me know.

Thanks and regards Rik

Comment: Please post you role definition, maybe you've granted access to Domain Admins group and that user is part of it

Comment: Or a local admin on the server